# change selected option with jquery not work

Tags: jquery

my HTML is

```
<select class="form-select ajax-processed shipping-recalculation-processed" name="customer_profile_shipping[addressbook]" id="edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook"><option value="none">-- Choose --</option>
<option selected="selected" value="20">tehran-righthand</option>
<option value="39"></option>
</select>
```

I want to try change selected option by clicking on another html element,also I mention the ajax set on this select option with change,
my aim is hide this element and according click on my html change the value of this select option (then the ajax should be triggered after it)

```
(function($){
  //$('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook').hide();
  $('.user-profile-address').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).prop('id');
    $('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook option[value="'+id+'"]').prop("selected",true);
///also I try this , I check click event handle correctly and passed true id (etc 20,39,none_
  //$('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook ').val(id);
    $('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook').change();
    //console.log(id);
    //console.log($('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook').val());
  });

  })(jQuery);
```

I try this code, the select option changed in appearance but when inspect element I see that select element not changed.

Comment: Simply use `.val()` like `$('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook').val(id);`

Comment: @Satpal I try it but noting happened, only in appearance changed not selected option, then not ajax triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ( I should call .change after change id)

```
  $('#edit-customer-profile-shipping-addressbook').val(id).change();
```